# Is this true for about abelian generating sets?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Given a finite abelian group $G$ which is genertaed by a set $S$.

**Question :**  Is there always exists a $S' \subseteq S$ which is a **basis** of $G$?

Seems true to me for example $\mathbb{Z}_6$, take $S = \{1,2,3\}$ contains a subset $\{2,3\}$ which is a basis.

A set $B$ is said to be a basis of a abelian group $G$ if $G=\langle B \rangle$.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "basis" here?

Comment: Perhaps by a basis you mean a minimal generating set? If that's so it's not hard to show that such exists.

Comment: Just to check: According to your definition, in your example, $\lbrace 1\rbrace$ is also a basis of $\Bbb Z_6$, correct?

Comment: Your definition of a basis is the same as a generating set...

Comment: Your new definition of a basis is not equivalent to your old one.  As verret writes, the new one is the same as the definition of a generating set.

Answer (score 3):

No: in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, $S=\{2,3\}$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, but $\{2\}$ and $\{3\}$ don't, and $\mathbb{Z}_{12} \neq \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 3 \rangle$.

Comment: This answer is correct only if one uses the definition of a basis appearing in the original version of the question.